# How to return highest average hourly value by year

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL table of readings taken every 10 minutes.
Columns are Date_Time (DateTime) and Steam_Flow (Real).
I would like to get a summary that only returns one row for each year that represents the highest average flow (by hour) for that year.

[image: Table and Expected Results]

I have the following so far...

```
SELECT
    CAST(Date_Time AS DATE) [Date],
    DATEPART(hour, Date_Time) [Hour],
    Avg(Steam_Flow) [Avg Flow]
FROM Boiler_Data
WHERE
    Date_Time >= '2018-12-31 21:00'
    and Date_time <= '2019-01-01 02:50:'
GROUP BY
    CAST(Date_Time AS DATE),
    DATEPART(hour, Date_Time)
ORDER BY [Avg Flow] Desc
```

Comment: Please post your sample data as tabular text or `INSERT` commands. That helps others providing proper answers.

Comment: Your syntax and the used functions indicate that the question is for ms sql server, not for mysql.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. When creating the question MySQL was the only choice available. The word MS gave me a warning that it cannot be used. If inappropriate here, let me know I will delete.

Comment: Considering that I could easily re-tag the question to sql server, your claim that mysql was the only available tag is a bit interesting.

Comment: I think what happened is that I tried SQL, then tried to add MS (where it told me no-no), did not realize that the SQL actually took, tried SQL again, saw only MYSQL as the closest remaining choice, took it then cleaned up the MS and the SQL (inadvertently). Either way I apologize, first time posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an aggregated query to compute the average flow per hour, and then aggregate by year in the outer query.

In MySQL :

```
SELECT x.date_year, MAX(x.Avg_Flow)
FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(date_time) date_year, avg(Flow) Avg_Flow
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY YEAR(date_time), DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %h')
) x
GROUP BY x.date_year
```

---

In SQL Server :

```
SELECT x.date_year, MAX(x.Avg_Flow)
FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(date_time) date_year, avg(Flow) Avg_Flow
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY YEAR(date_time), DATEADD(hour, datediff(hour, 0, date_time), 0)
) x
GROUP BY x.date_year
```

Comment: Thaks for the reply! Is date_year supposed to be date_time? Either way, I get "Date_Time is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." even though it is in the Group By clause.

Comment: @Brian : I edited the query, pls give it another try

Comment: Thanks GMB for the friendly help, that worked perfectly! I understand the inner select, when I run it I get the avg of the hours. I partially understand outer selecting the max from within the inner results. What I am not familiar with is how the variable "X" makes this work. I will try to research this, any hints at what I should be learning to understand this? Thanks again!

Comment: @Brian : `x` is just an alias for the data that is returned by the inner query, which is used in the outer query

Comment: Checked. Thanks again! The x acts as a place holder so to speak, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the constraits of your tables and type of variables:

```
SELECT MAX(Steam_Flow), YEAR(Date_Time) FROM Boiler_Data GROUP BY YEAR(Date_Time);
```